# How to find all rows matching one of multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have a table, called V (as seen in the screenshot below). How would I find all the rows with a given value in either the `IN` or `OUT` columns?

For example, finding all rows with "#10:0" in `IN` or `OUT` below.

[image: Screenshot]

My best attempt is

```
SELECT FROM V WHERE ???(OUT OR IN) = '#10:0'
```

but I don't know what should be in place of the `???`.

Comment: Hi, relatively to your image, what should be the output result you expect from a query ? Could you give an example ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case you have a defined edge @rid so it would be better to start your query from E and not V.
By this way you'll have to use the `inV()`, `outV()` and `bothV()` functions.

**Examples**:

1) Getting the IN vertex (`#12:1`)

```
select expand(inV()) from #10:0
```

2) Getting the OUT vertex (`#12:0`)

```
select expand(outV()) from #10:0
```

2) Getting both vertices connected to `#10:0` (`#12:0` and `#12:1`)

```
select expand(bothV()) from #10:0
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

based on your query i guess:

```
    SELECT FROM V WHERE OUT = '#10:0' OR IN = '#10:0'
```

but the screenshot really hurt my eyes